# Is there a BinaryFormatter alternative which runs in medium trust

Tags: c#, .net, security, serialization

I'm running a website in a hosted environment (i.e. I don't have control over permissions) and it is set to run at medium trust. The code i'm using serializes object for saving in a database and uses the BinaryFormatter. However this throws an SecurityException running under medium trust.

Is there an alternative binary formatter which would run under medium trust?

Comment: Why serializing an object into binary for saving into a database?

Comment: I'm implementing a solution using CQRS and eventsourcing so storing the event objects in a single table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. For those interested i ended up using Newtonsofts JsonSerializer 
with the BsonWriter which works in medium trust. See Example code below:

```
public object Deserialize<T>(System.IO.Stream serializationStream)
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    T instance;

    BsonReader reader = new BsonReader(serializationStream);
    instance = serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);

    return instance;
}

public void Serialize(System.IO.Stream serializationStream, object graph)
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(serializationStream))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, graph);
    }
}
```

Comment: `using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;`
after installing via NuGet: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

Answer (score 3):

The BinaryFormatter is not designed to work in partial trust.  The .NET Framework has other available formatters which work in partial trust:

- [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)
- [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)
- [NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx)

The XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer are appropriate for serializing types like records, where the object graphs are finite and all types to be serialized are known ahead of time.  They can also interoperate with other non-.NET frameworks.  The NetDataContractSerializer is more appropriate for general-purpose .NET framework serialization, where you might not know all the types in the graph to be serialized ahead of time.  The biggest downside is that it can't easily interoperate with other non-.NET frameworks, as it includes type information in the serialized stream.

Regardless of which serializer you use, certain types simply cannot be serialized at all in partial trust.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412175.aspx for more info.